# Regular expression for a real number with comma or dot for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, expression

I want to know what I'm doing wrong in this code for checking a real number:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/([0-9]+[\.|,][0-9]*)|([0-9]*[\.|,][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)/g);
var invalid = this.value.match(regex);
```

The above doesn't work for me while the expression

```
([0-9]+[\.|,][0-9]*)|([0-9]*[\.|,][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)
```

works in the tester.

Answer (score 5):

Do

```
var regex = new RegExp("([0-9]+[.|,][0-9])|([0-9][.|,][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)/g);([0-9]+[.|,][0-9])|([0-9][.|,][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)", 'g');
```

or

```
var regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9])|([0-9][.|,][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)/g​;
```

Two constructs are possible : `new RegExp(string,'g')` or `/somestring/g`. Don't mix them. In your case of a constant regexp, it will be more efficient to choose the second one because it is precompiled.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: +1 - i prefer the `/.../` construct since you don't have to string escape it.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to match pipes…

Comment: yappa. besides it matches pipes it could be simplified as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, you do not need to do `new RegExp()` on a regular expression that is not within a string.

`/regexp/rule` OR `new RegExp("regexp", "rule");`

secondly:

why do you use `[0-9]` if you could just use `\d`?

third:

why do you use `[.|,]`? do you want to match | aswell? `[.,]` would do the job you want to achieve.

fourth:

check this against a numerical string: `/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/`

you can do like this:

```
var regexp = /^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/;

alert(regexp.test("0")); // true
alert(regexp.test("1")); // true
alert(regexp.test("01")); // false (or check out the regex at the bottom)
alert(regexp.test("123")); // true
alert(regexp.test("1234")); // false
alert(regexp.test("123,4")); // false
alert(regexp.test("123,456,789,012")); // true
alert(regexp.test("123,456,789,012.")); // false
alert(regexp.test("123,456,789,012.12341324")); // true
alert(regexp.test("0.12341324")); // true
```

in case you do want to match something like 0,000,000.0000 aswell you could use this regex:

`/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/`

in case you want +- in front you can add what Bergi mentioned.
my regex would then look like this:

`/^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/`

or: `/^[+-]?(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/`

as Bergi mentioned you should know how to have . as grouping operator and , as delimiter. for that you just need to replace `,` with `\.` and `\.` with `,`

there are the expressions with replaced , and .

```
/^?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?$/ <- matches 00,000,000.00000
/^?(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*|0)(?:,\d+)?$/ <- matches 1,123,123,123.1234
/^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?$/ <- matches -00,000.0
/^[+-]?(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*|0)(?:,\d+)?$/ <- matches -12,123.12345
```

Comment: edited regex again. now it also makes sure something like: 00,000,001 is invalid

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the comma as a grouping operator, but rather as the decimal delimiter (alternative to the dot)

Comment: if he wants it the other way he would only need to replace \. with , and , with \.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the support, yes.. the thing is to be very open (nusty thing) to the way the user prefer to use , or . so we want to validate almost every case with , or . so it wouldn't be exactly a real number sometimes... but we decided to prefer to have some errors than to make the user to fill up the form/field again because of usability questions. And no, i didn't want to include | as a valid char. :/

Comment: my code does contain | but as "or" operator and not as char :D give it a try and tell me what else you need this to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

```
/[+-]?(?:\d*[.,])?\d+/
```

It uses the shortcut `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, also I don't think you want to match the pipe as a decimal delimiter. Square brackets define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), in which special chars loose their meaning (`.` doesn't need escaping, `|` doesn't mean OR) - you probably meant `(\.|,)`. Also I'm not sure whether you really want to match floas without decimal digits (e.g. `"12,"`) - I've omitted them; and I've allowed an optional sign in the beginning.

Comment: …which are valid numbers, aren't them?

Comment: true thing but it would not match 12.123,412 or 12,123.412 completely

Comment: Yes, but the OP's regex doesn't match them either. Not sure if he needs them, or do you want those @Rimbuaj?

Comment: for me it seems like he does not know regex too well wich means he could mean anything unless he tells us.

Comment: that's right , i needed something very tolerant... Jan, you're right, i dont have a glue of regex, i forgot everything!